SSD Certificate replication to grant (sleep) status access via networked devices
By installing a fraudulent ticket by any installer like Bluestack for example you can force a Network device to remain in the power/on=1 state.
The purpose of this would be to connect to a drive without leaving and logged events or file interaction changes via metadata.
I have ran several VM environments and have been able to implement this as a workaround to accessing a networked pc.
Installed a windows certified (modified) certificate to allow the MBR HDD to be access while in sleep status. (only effective in a physical Cat-5 etc. connection. Wifi or BT access has not been tested as far as I know.)
